# Is there a word for a person who likes to bathe a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests

I like to spend a lot of time bathing..I kind of enjoy it...I just cant get enough of it..I can be under shower for hours. Is there a word for me?
I tried googling around but all I could find was words like bath-lovers , shower-lovers. Is there something more formal and widely accepted?

Comment: Have you looked online to see if you can find any terms for this?

Comment: I tried but could not find any answer. Also had a tough time explaining my exact requirement for searching online...

Comment: The first one I thought of when reading your question was [water baby](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=water+baby) but that's quite informal. Can you edit that you tried into your question? It seems like a simple thing, but so many people don't do any research and end up getting closevoted for being off-topic. As long as you mention that you did try to find something you'll generally be okay.

Comment: There's also ***aquaphile*** but I think that's more for an actual water fetish where it arouses you, which I don't think is quite what you're after.

Comment: Not that i didn't come across **aquaphile** before, but as you suggested its more of water and not bath..

Comment: The stereotypical obsessive-compulsive disorder is ***hand-washing***, but I don't think even that one has a dedicated name for the sufferer, so I doubt there'll be one for people who're obsessed with whole-body ablutions.

Comment: I honestly don't think we're going to get any advance on ***water baby*** for this.

Comment: [Ablutophilia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ablutophilia) *- a paraphilia involving sexual excitement by baths or showers.*

Comment: This cries out for coinage. We could borrow from French and make *"baignard,"* or go to Greek for *"baineaphile"* - which admittedly sounds paraphilic, but at least is etymologically consistent.

Comment: @Rob_Ster: Appreciate your suggestion, can you direct me to something to read about this

Comment: I would tend to think of "water baby" as someone who wants to be submerged in the water a lot, typically enjoying swimming.  Altho' I'm a little confused by the question: the title refers specifically to "*bath* a lot" (as does one of Op's comments), whereas the second part of the question also refers to showering.  Because I think of "water baby" as implying submersion, it could also apply to bathing - but not to showering.

Comment: There probably is a literary/mythological reference to someone who was always washing.  But all I can think of is "Rub-a-dub dub, three men in a tub".

Comment: @HotLicks I prefer the version that has the three tradesmen ogling three *maids* in a tub, not that there is anything wrong with your version.

Comment: How about bathaholic

Comment: How about Bathlord? Washmonkey? Ensoapenator?  :)

Comment: How about *Aqua-freak*? (Inspired from the word *couch potato*!).

Comment: The most common word I know of that describes this type of person is **clean**

Comment: There's not any common word for this. Make up your own!

Comment: How about *puckered*?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider, [***showerer***](http://fr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=showerer)

> *n.* someone who showers abundantly
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/showerer)

Answer (score 0):

**Ablutomania**

I think this word is not entirely accepted, but is useful.

> Morbid preoccupation with thoughts about cleanliness; obsession with bathing, [washing](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ablutomania). *Yourdictionary.com*

However, it is a medical term

> Compulsive washing of [oneself](http://www.rightdiagnosis.com/medical/ablutomania.htm). *.rightdiagnosis.com*

and I think worth using if a single word is needed. A person with this attachment would be an **ablutomaniac**

Answer (score -1):

> someone who showers abundantly

KULI (word inspired from a friend)

Comment: The first page of search results for kuli shower are mostly porn sites. This seems like a joke answer.